# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this error message:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

main.js:

```
var React       = require('react');
var ReactDOM    = require('react-dom');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router';
var Route = BrowserRouter.Route;

import App from 'App';

const routes = (
<BrowserRouter>

    <Route path="/" component={App} />

</BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

---

App.js:

```
var React       = require('react');
var ReactDOM    = require('react-dom');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');


export default class App extends React.Component {



    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>       
                <h2>masoud</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }


}
```

I changed this line:

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router';
```

to

```
import BrowserRouter from 'react-router';
```

or

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router';
```

but it doesn't worked and I got the same error.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `default` keyword? means `export default class App extends React.Component` becomes `export class App extends React.Component`

Comment: what version of *react-router* are importing?

Comment: "react-router": "^4.2.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
import App from 'App';
```

it looks for the App component to be in node_modules package named App which is not what you intent, You need to specify the `path/to/App` while importing

```
import App from 'path/to/App';
```

Also BrowserRouter is an export from `react-router-dom` package and not `react-router`, you need to first install it like

```
npm install -S react-router-dom
```

and then write

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Check the **[documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)**

Comment: now I got this error: `ReferenceError: BrowserRouter is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Might be because your App import, try this,

```
import App from './App';
```

I assume that *App.js* and *main.js* are in the same root directory

Answer (score 0):

Try  to change `import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router';`

to

```
import BrowserRouter from 'react-router';
```

also make sure that you are using the right react-router package. Depending on what version you are using you have to `import BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: Did you check the react-router documentation before answer, if not its probably a comment and not an answer to the question

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, this happened to me before and this was my solution. I was using the wrong version of react router and had a conflict in my package.json. I'm not sure what version he's using so I threw in those extra suggestions.